# Laravel Validation exists within company_id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-excel

Im using maatwebsite Laravel Excel, when trying to import I have an `exists` validation of my `employee_code` which is a `foreign key`, what I want to achieve is how would I add a condition on this that I want to only check within a certain `company_id`

For example, the users `company_id` is `1` when the user wants to input `2` on `employee_code` it shouldn't accept and send an error message. The `company_id` isn't needed in importing, just provided a clearer visual to understand.

```
________________________
employee_code|company_id
1            |1
2            |2 //Error should be thrown here
3            |1
```

This is my validation on my company_code

```
'employee_code' => 'required|exists:employee_information,code',
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear question
But you can make custom validation on laravel for you code
with `php artisan make:rule`
This is laravel document [laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

maybe  help you